# Word choice: "like" or "as"?

Tags: word-choice

> "*You are going to fight in the war like David once did.*"

I have two questions:

1. Should "*like*" be replaced with "*as*"?
2. Is it ever acceptable to use "*like*" in this sentence even though "*as*" is the proper word to use?

Comment: Welcome to E.L. & U. None. I am sorry to bother you with this, as I believe somebody would be glad to help you, but there is something we need from you first. Please provide us with your own comparison of the two words in a dictionary of your choice, and tell us what remains ambiguous about the matter as clearly as is possible. [The help center's guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/glmbv5y) require questioners to perform some basic research before a question may be answered, for reasons that are mostly explained in Jeff Atwood's post "[Are Some Questions Too Simple?](http://tinyurl.com/create.php)"

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of ['like' versus 'as'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16039/like-versus-as) and [Is there a difference beyween 'like' and 'as'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194244/is-there-any-difference-between-like-and-as)—among (probably) a number of other, similar questions asked at this site over the years. Please check the answers to the two linked questions and see whether they answer your question.

Comment: Ah, [Is there any difference between 'like' and 'as'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194244/is-there-any-difference-between-like-and-as) is the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

In standard English,  *as*, and not *like*, is the correct choice when a *clause* follows:

> You are going to fight
> in the war **as** David
> once **did**

If no clause follows, only *like* is correct:

> He speaks like his father

However, in casual speech, some native speakers are heard using *like* when *as* is due.

Comment: What do you want, good grammar or good taste?

Comment: Could you add a supporting reference, please?